# Is it possible to compile an audio file together with my c# file into a single exe?

Tags: c#, audio, exe

So I have a script that, when run, plays an audio file which I currently have in the same folder. I would like to consolidate the two of these into a single .exe, but I'm not sure if this is possible or not. Does anyone know specifics on this?

Comment: What kind of script? What language?

Comment: @lukas c#. It says in my tags.

Comment: Well C# is not really a scripting language.

Comment: @lukas Perhaps I am using the wrong word. I simply meant that I have a c# file I wish to compile together with an audio file. I have edited it out for your sake.

Comment: Add the C# back in.  We need to know what language and platform you are working with.  On SO this is done using tags.  Just change script to program or app in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy way is to:

1. Open Visual Studios.
2. Start a new C# project.
3. Add a new Resources File to the project (open it in the designer if it does not automatically).
4. Click the "Add Resource" button at the top of the window and select your sound file.
5. Write code to play the file (I assume the script can be ported to this, let us know if you need help on this).  To access the file use `Namespace.ResourceFile.FileName` where Namespace is the namesapce of the project, ResourceFile is the name of the resource file you added (default is "Resource1.resx"), and FileName is the name of the file you added.

It will make things easier if after you add the sound file you check the top left button on the window.  It will either be "Files" or "Audio" though the window often opens to "Strings".  Make a note of what this currently says so you can switch back to this view later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just by setting the audio file Build Action property to Embedded Resource. I suppose that you have added audio file to your project to right click on it > Properties then do what I have said above.(while i think it's not a good practice) 
 hope it would help